# Remember the iteration when a condition was met

Tags: c, avr, avr-gcc

I'm working on AtMega8 in Eclipse.

In a for loop I want to check if pins of `PIND` are `1`. If so I want to have a char array of pins that were `1` in a certain iteration with the number of that iteration.

If some pin of `PIND` was `1` in a certain iteration, it will not be `1` in any other iteration.

For example:

```
1. PIND = 0b00110011
2. PIND = 0b10001000
3. PIND = 0b01000100
Result      23112311
```

Comment: It's not clear what is the relation between the numbers in the question...

Comment: Im doing short circuit tester. I want to know which pins are shorted with which pins. In first iteration I will set only one pin of PORTD to "1" and then check other pins from PORTD if they are "high". If so, they are shorted with this exact pin that I set as "1" in this iteration. In next iteration I will change pin set as "1" to next pin and check again. If some pins will be "high" I want to mark them again. If not, I want them to remain 0. I need to multiple them by the number of iteration because I need to know which pins are shorted with which pins so they cant be all just 0 or 1.

Comment: Many words, no clarification. What is the relation between `0b00110011`, `0b10001000`, `0b01000100` and `23112311`???

Comment: `0b00110011` - first loop ( I multiple it *1 and get `00110011`) ; `0b10001000` - second loop ( I multiple it *2 and get `2002000`); `0b01000100` - third loop (I multiple it *3 and get `03000300`); After all iterations I want to "sum" numbers to get output - `23112311`

Answer (score 1):

Although the idea looks awkward to me, the requirement can be fulfilled using the following code:

```
char arr[]="00000000";
uint8_t p;

for (i=1; i<=ITERATIONS; i++)
{
    p = PIND;
    for (j=0; j<8; j++)
    {
        if ( (p >> j) & 1) // Check the `j`s bit
        {
            arr[j] = i + '0'; // Convert number `i` into a char representing it
        }
    }
}
```

** You might want to reverse the order array is written..

Comment: Would be really nice if the downvoter commented their view.

Answer (score 0):

```
int shorted[8] = {0}; // hold results    
int i, pin = 0, iter = 1;

while(pin < 8)
{
    PORTD = 1 << pin;

    // find all the pins that are shorted to the pin on this iteration
    for(i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    {
         if(PIND & (1 << i))
         {
              shorted[i] = iter;
         }
    }

    // Look for the next pin never shorted. Break while loop if all are done
    pin = 8;
    for(i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    {
         if(shorted[i] == 0)
         {
             pin = i;
             break;
         }
    }  

    ++iter;
}
```